# Java8-runtime-headless dependency for Scala-2.12.2 with .deb and rpm

Tags: scala

I am trying to install Scala-2.12.2 on Ubuntu16.04 and Ubuntu16.10 on Linux using the [.deb](https://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/2.12.2/scala-2.12.2.deb) . While installing the .deb, I am getting the error that " scala depends on java8-runtime-headless; however: Package java8-runtime-headless is not installed."

This dependency is not required when I try to intsall Scala-2.12.2 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) using the scala [rpm](https://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/2.12.2/scala-2.12.2.rpm).Any idea why there is a dependency difference in the .deb and rpm format.

I am using IBM java version "1.8.0" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6480sr4fp5-20170421_01(SR4 FP5)) for the build.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to download `open-jdk-8` as the error messages asks for. In Ubuntu 16.04, it is already available in the Universe repository. Make sure that you have it in your `/etc/apt/source.list` file.

Then, issue the usual commands

```
apt-get update
apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

These lines will install the full `open-jdk-8`, not just its *headless* version, used for applications that in which the [display device, keyboard, or mouse is lacking](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html).

Good luck !

Comment: To add PPA, run: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error message on Ubuntu, however I have Java 8 installed (manually installed latest Oracle version). After installing it works. Java is on the classpath (i manually linked /usr/bin/java to my install)

I hope it is the same for you, too.

This is my action log:

```
$ scala
The program 'scala' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install scala

$ wget https://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/2.12.2/scala-2.12.2.deb

$ sudo dpkg -i scala-2.12.2.deb
Selecting previously unselected package scala.
(Reading database ... 1342927 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack scala-2.12.2.deb ...
Unpacking scala (2.12.2-400) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of scala:
 scala depends on java8-runtime-headless; however:
  Package java8-runtime-headless is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package scala (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 scala

$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.12.2 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL and     Lightbend, Inc.
```

Comment: Yes, Scala .deb can be installed successfully with OpenJDK. I am trying to run the debian with the IBM SDK. I dont want to install  oracle/openjdk to satisfy the  java8-runtime-headless dependency.Is ther  any package related to IBM java which can help in resolving the issue

Answer (score 0):

I also had Java 8 manually installed and got exactly the same error message. I fixed it by running `sudo apt --fix-broken install`. It identified the missing dependencies (including openjdk-8-jre-headless) and installed them. 
Everthing is fine now.